# Increment Java Fied Value Using Objectweb ASM Bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am currently learning about Java bytecode and I got stuck at a part.

Lets say I have a super class that contains the integer **currentPos**.
I generated a method that has to generate a child class and increments the **currentPos** but somehow it is throwing a stack underflow error.

Here's my code:

```
runMethod.instructions.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETFIELD, "me/looka/bfc/FooSuperClass", "currentPos", "I"));
runMethod.instructions.add(new InsnNode(ICONST_1));
runMethod.instructions.add(new InsnNode(IADD));
runMethod.instructions.add(new FieldInsnNode(PUTFIELD, "me/looka/bfc/FooSuperClass", "currentPos", "I"));
```

This is supposed to increment currentPos right as it goes through the following steps:
Put current value into stack
Add the value 1 into the stack
Add both added values together, pop those 2 values off the stack and push the added value.
Set the field with the current value of the stack
Pop that added value

Comment: Put your code in your question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed the code by adding two ALOAD_0 opcodes at the beginning of the code. This way the GETFIELD gets called then the increment happens then because there's another ALOAD_0 it will allow be to set the field.

Answer (score 1):

`getfield`/`putfield` are used for non-static fields. If the field is static, you need `getstatic`/`putstatic`. Otherwise, you need to supply the object to reference the fields from. Assuming said object is in local slot 0, (where the this parameter is normally kept), you'd want something like

```
runMethod.instructions.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 0));
runMethod.instructions.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD, 0));
runMethod.instructions.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETFIELD, "me/looka/bfc/FooSuperClass", "currentPos", "I"));
runMethod.instructions.add(new InsnNode(ICONST_1));
runMethod.instructions.add(new InsnNode(IADD));
runMethod.instructions.add(new FieldInsnNode(PUTFIELD, "me/looka/bfc/FooSuperClass", "currentPos", "I"));
```